# Expose and/or operators in Views exposed filters?

Tags: views

How do I expose (to the user) the `and/or` operators in a set of exposed view filters?

[image: and/or]

In other words, how do I let the user change the way the search filters interact with each other?

I don't see this option in the built-in settings or in the [Better Exposed Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module.

Comment: Interesting question. I don't think there is a module for that, but hopefully someone will prove me wrong. I'm very curious how these options would be presented to the end user, because good UX for interfaces like this can be very hard.